# Correct parameters to compile wxWidgets on Codeblocks 10.05

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have compiled wxWidgets with the following parameters:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 USE_OPENGL=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=1
```

But when I want to build the project by default in codeblocks, throws me the following error:

```
cannot find -lwxmsw28
```

What's going on? What parameters need to build this library?

Comment: What version of wxWidgets did you build? The built library should be in `[your wxWidgets directory]\lib\gcc_dll` and will have a name something like `wxmsw311.dll`.

Comment: @JavierRodriguez, you can drop "UNICODE=1", it is set by default. Since you are starting I would guess you need "BUILD=debug" to be able to easily debug you application. "MONOLITHIC=1" is rarely used, it means you are building one huge library and will rely on the linker to do the right thing and bring the necessary functions into the binary.

Comment: So, the command I'd build it would be "mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 USE_OPENGL=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=debug". That is if you are building latest 3.0/3.1 code.If you are really need to build 2.8 (for whatever reason), you do need to add "UNICODE=1".

Comment: No, I'm sorry but the library is still missing. cannot find -lwxmsw28 with parameters: USE_XRC=1 USE_OPENGL=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=debug" and USE_XRC=1 USE_OPENGL=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 BUILD=release" What I can do? Note: my wxWidgets version is 2.8.12

Answer (score 0):

If your `make` command didn't give any errors, the library must have been built, however it is not enough for Code::Blocks to find it -- think about it, how would it know where to look? You need to configure it by entering the path to the `lib` subdirectory of the directory where you built wxWidgets in the linker options of your project to make this work.

Also, please **strongly** consider using a less than 10 year old version, there is no reason to use anything less than 3.0 unless you're working on some existing legacy project (and even then you should update it and switch to 3.0 nevertheless).